# Make all fonts larger on the Macbook Air 11" or 13"

Tags: macos, display, font, resolution

Instead of getting a Macbook Pro 13" or 15", I was thinking of getting the Macbook Air 13" or 11", but checking the machines at Apple store, it turns out the density of pixels of the screen of the Macbook Air 11" or 13" is larger, so the font appears more "dense", and therefore smaller.

It turns out that the Macbook Pro 13" has smaller pixel density, and the 15" model has even smaller density, so they can have larger fonts, without needing to squint the eyes. The 17" model also has high font density as well.

If I want to get the Macbook Air 13", is there a way under Lion to make all the fonts larger (the webpage, the menu bar, all apps), without changing the resolution of the machine to something not the native resolution? (Native resolution is optimal on each machine.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to change font sizes system-wide while preserving UI resolution?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/474/is-there-a-way-to-change-font-sizes-system-wide-while-preserving-ui-resolution)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is without deep hacking, no, you cannot make fonts larger in *all* applications and in the menu bar but not change from the native resolution.

Many applications do have zoom features (including Safari, Finder, Address Book, Mail, etc.), but the way to make text larger in each app is, unfortunately, different from app to app.

Comment: yes, zooming works extremely well and it's easy to do using the multitouch trackpad of the macbook air

Comment: This reason alone means I will never use a Mac

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Settings", then click on "Displays" & change the Resolution to "Best for display", mine was stuck on "Scaled" after I had it hooked up to the TV. Personally, I think 1440x900 looks best on my laptop, but if you click "Scaled" then 1024x640 the general font will get even bigger.

Comment: this is using the non-native resolution... and in general will make text and photos more pixelated