# Can I change the font systemwide (10.8.3)

Tags: macos, font

Is it possible to change the systems font? (finder, alerts, menus etc)

Comment: You should not change system fonts unless you’re experienced with fonts and know how the change will affect your computer.

Answer (score 7):

Here are the corresponding hidden preferences:

```
defaults write -g NSSystemFont LucidaGrande
defaults write -g NSSystemFontSize -int 13
defaults write -g NSBoldSystemFont LucidaGrande-Bold
defaults write -g NSBoldSystemFontSize -int 13
defaults write -g NSFont Helvetica
defaults write -g NSFontSize -int 12 
defaults write -g NSFixedPitchFont Menlo-Regular
defaults write -g NSFixedPitchFontSize -int 11
defaults write -g NSMessageFont LucidaGrande
defaults write -g NSMessageFontSize -int 13
defaults write -g NSLabelFont LucidaGrande
defaults write -g NSLabelFontSize -int 10
defaults write -g NSToolTipsFont LucidaGrande
defaults write -g NSToolTipsFontSize -int 11
defaults write -g NSTitleBarFont LucidaGrande
defaults write -g NSTitleBarFontSize -int 13
defaults write -g NSPaletteFont LucidaGrande
defaults write -g NSPaletteFontSize -int 10
```

They don't affect windows shown by processes owned by root, like the force quit window. `sudo defaults write -g` (which modifies `/var/root/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`) affects only them.

There is no way to change many fonts (like the font used on the menu bar) and text elements are not aligned correctly when using different fonts. You can also [replace Lucida Grande.ttc](http://macthemes.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=16793121) with some other font.

Answer (score 5):

A third party application [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) can change these, on its Fonts screen:

[image]

TinkerTool works by setting defaults, so it is reasonable to expect there is an equivalent `defaults write` command.

Comment: Please be aware that Apple does not recommend tinkering with system fonts. http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11149

Comment: Tinker Tool just changes the preferred system font. You will see these fonts only if the developer of the app wants you to see them. So almost never.

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r - most apps will read these as the default font on the first run then you can set them

Comment: Im on Mavericks. I see no changes except for plain html and mails.

Comment: Please dont use it on Yosemite it messed up my fonts entirely.

Comment: DUPE of http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/52608/46541

Comment: @Buscar웃SD Why comment = the question has already been closed as a dupe and answers are not dupes - if an answer is a duplicate then the question is a duplicate. So everything is in order here. It just took us a month to spot the duplicate. (But then Stack Exchange does not give all the help it could in finding dupes e.g. First Post queasy does not show the possible dies where other screens do)