# How can I use a newly installed font as an input source?

Tags: keyboard, font, language, input-source

I just installed a new font, and I'd like to be able to type in it, system-wide, and not just within the confines of some application (e.g. MS Word.)  I already type in other languages using the Language & Text preference pane.  Is there any way to use the TTF as a keyboard?

Thanks

Comment: Exactly what font and language are you talking about?  OS X is Unicode based, and you change keyboards rather than fonts to type different scripts.

Comment: PaleoHebrew... the predecessor to the Hebrew language :-D

Comment: In that case you do not want a new font but a new keyboard layout (and if the language is "exotic" then probably a new input method).

One way to make your own (but it will take some time to do so) is to use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) program to create your own layout.

Comment: Are you using some non-standard font which maps characters to Latin, or a standard Unicode font which uses the Phoenician range U+10900?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleo-Hebrew_alphabet

Comment: PS I made a keyboard layout for Phoenician range a few years ago you are welcome to try.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46870715/k/Phoenician.keylayout

Comment: @TomG Awesome!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to type in another language you will need not only a font but also a keyboard layout.

For some languages you might want to create your own, and for that you can use the [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) software.

Answer (score 2):

You can not simply "type in another font" system-wide, since it is each application's responsibility to include support for fonts on its own. Installing a new font merely gives you the possibility to use it in applications, for example a plain-text application will never be able to handle fonts at all.

If what you want is to change the system font itself, then the answer is here: [Can I change the font systemwide (10.8.3)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86864/can-i-change-the-font-systemwide-10-8-3)

Comment: informative, thanks, but I think what I want is something like the installation of a new input source.

Answer (score 1):

A source for Unicode Paleo Hebrew and related fonts is at

http://culmus.sourceforge.net/ancient/index.html

Input for most can be via Character Viewer or the OS X Hebrew keyboard layout or a Phoenician layout available at

http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46870715/k/Phoenician.keylayout