# increase font for all apps/menus in mac

Tags: macos, mac, font

Is there an app to increase/change default fontsize for all applications in mac ?
It is really painful for me to read default fonts or to increase fontsize in every app I open, and even worse, the fontsize in many menus(as well as Finder match results) can not be modified!

Comment: Did you try the Accessibility options for Zoom ?

Comment: Yes, I did. As the word 'zoom' implies, it does not increase the fontsize. Even worse, 'Accessibility-Zoom' destroys all the layout.

Comment: So you do not want to zoom in, just increase the font and that system wide.

Comment: You are right, I simply want all texts to be larger.

Comment: It is not simple at all, otherwise there would be a user control for it. But look the answers in here http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/86864/46541