# Use different font alternative stylistic set of an open type font on Mac

Tags: macos, font, font-book

I currently know the feature code. Vs Code supports it in settings.json. I wonder if I could change the installed font to that stylistic set. For example, if I use customized font in Mac terminal, I wish the displayed style is not the default style but an alternative stylistic set of that font.

Comment: It sound like you wan’t to change the font systemwide on your Mac.  However, it’s confusing when mentioning VS Code. Do you want this for an App or something else?  What feature code are you referring to?

Comment: I want this for the whole system, for example, if i use the font as terminal font, it should display the alternative stylistic set instead of the default style. Considering feature codes, they are: `'ss03', 'ss04', 'ss05', 'ss08', 'ss12', 'ss13', 'ss14', 'ss03', 'cv01'`.

Comment: Have you see the answers here? https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/86864/119271

Comment: If i follow this link, it can change the system font to the font i want to use. But i wanna use different stylistic sets of one font. Mac terminal supports using customised font. So if i change the font to the font i wanna use in the terminal, i wish the displayed style is not the default style.

Comment: What OS version are you on? What is the font? When you say "Globally", you mean wherever that font is used, you want to use the alternate set, e.g. Swash lettering, Small Caps, etc. Or just in a specific app, e.g. Terminal. You may be able to configure the font selection panel of an app to use the alternate sets for something, but I don't think there's a 'global' way of doing this.

Comment: Yeah, i changed the description to make it more clear. I am on Macos 13.1. The font is Julia Mono. I want to use the font in apps that support choosing customized font. I discovered that VSCode could use a different stylistic set by modifying `editor.ligatures` in settings.json. I wonder if Mac provide such a function to change the default style of the font to an alternative stylistic set.

Answer (score 1):

The font selector in the Preferences of Apple's Terminal.app supports MacOS's standard font panel, where you can select OpenType features, such as alternate sets:

[image]

The contents of the Typography panel will depend upon the features that the typeface supports.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: But when i clicked the selections, there is no effect on Terminal display. The Mac Terminal doesn't support alternative stylistic sets? After I closed the selection window and reopened, the selections are lost.

Comment: @lptlk Well, if it doesn't work, then it's not possible.