# Screen Resolution/Scaling Issue in iMac mid-2011 and LG 27UL550W

Tags: display, imac, resolution, 4k

Good afrernoon!

I've bought a new monitor and I'm having some troubles at setting it's resolution/scaling factor.

First of all, I don't have the option to set text scaling as some tutorials make reference to (https://macreports.com/how-to-change-the-text-size-in-macos/)

Then, I'm having some trouble at choosing a sharp resolution for it. The only ones that "work" are 1080p HiDPI, 1440p and 2160p. But the first one makes everything huge, the second one looks awful and the third one makes everything tiny.

I've tested a few apps, like SwitchResX or RDM, but neither of them have worked.

P.D.: My new monitor is a LG 27UL550W and my Mac is currently using macOS High Sierra.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried the other resolutions in the Display Preferences pane by Option-clicking the "Scaled" radio button to show additional resolutions?

Comment: Can I assume you meant LG 27UL550W when you entered LG 27UW550? What screen size does the Mac have? Are you using HDMI or DisplayPort on the monitor?

Comment: @agarza. I've tried using the "shorcut" to display other resolutions but the options shown are even worse.

Comment: @David Anderson Yes, I mispelled the model in the title. I've just changed ;)

Comment: Ivan: OK, but what about the other questions I asked: What screen size does the Mac have? Are you using HDMI or DisplayPort on the monitor?

Comment: @David Anderson. Sorry I didn't saw them. Is 21.5" iMac 1080p and the monitor is conected using a Mini-DisplayPort to DisplayPort which is compatible with 4K. This cable: https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.amazon.es/IVANKY-DisplayPort-Compatible-2010-2015-2009-2015/dp/B07NTV64J2&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjNhav3__T0AhXb8uAKHTnFBoQQFnoECAoQAg&usg=AOvVaw0U_npKsNgH9Y575icE1CdI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three resolutions you have tried are the three highest resolutions the display is capable of. There are no other resolutions you can achieve that are between these resolutions. The rest of this answer documents (supports) what I have already stated.

Below is a table showing the horizontal and vertical pixels associated with the resolutions given in your question. This table was derived from the following webpages.

ViewSonic: [What Is Monitor Resolution? Resolutions and Aspect Ratios Explained](https://www.viewsonic.com/library/tech/monitor-resolution-aspect-ratio/#What_Are_Some_Common_Monitor_Resolutions)
Wikipedia: [4K resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4K_resolution#2160p_resolution)

| Resolution | Pixels |
| --- | --- |
| 1080p | 1920 x 1080 |
| 1440p | 2560 x 1440 |
| 2160p | 3840 x 2160 |

Below are tables taken from the [LG 27UL550 owner's manual](https://gscs-b2c.lge.com/downloadFile?fileId=ggLNIspG8U6HdrTMnl8Vw)

[image: DisplayPort]
[image: HDMI]
[image: HDMI Timing]

### References

- [Make it easier to see what’s on the screen](https://support.apple.com/en-mn/guide/mac-help/mchld786f2cd/10.13/mac/10.13), *Mac Help (Apple)*
- [Using a Retina display](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202471), *Apple*, Mar 31 `21
- [iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2011) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp623?locale=en_US), *Apple*, Mar 24 `21
- [How to Change the Text Size in macOS](https://macreports.com/how-to-change-the-text-size-in-macos/), *macReports*, Feb 7 `21
- [I Bought This 4K Monitor, What Else Do I need For Native 4K?](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/i-bought-this-4k-monitor-what-else-do-i-need-for-native-4k.2221743/), *MacRumors (Forum)*, Jan 30 `20
- [Why is there no scaling in OS X for high res monitors?](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/why-is-there-no-scaling-in-os-x-for-high-res-monitors.2134275/), *MacRumors (Forum)*, Aug 27 `18
- [How do I scale everything up on my Mac Screen without decreasing resolution?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256143/how-do-i-scale-everything-up-on-my-mac-screen-without-decreasing-resolution), *Ask Different*, Oct 6 `16
- [How to Increase All System Font Size in Mac OS X](https://osxdaily.com/2016/05/23/increase-system-text-size-mac-os-x-scaled-resolution/), *OSXDaily*, May 23 `16
- [DPI scaling settings on macOS / OS X (HiDPI display)](https://www.eizoglobal.com/support/compatibility/dpi_scaling_settings_mac_os_x/), *EISO*, Nov `14
- [Get More Usable Screen Space on a Retina MacBook Pro by Adjusting Resolution](https://osxdaily.com/2014/04/14/change-retina-macbook-screen-resolution-more-space/), *OSXDaily*, Apr 14 `14
- [How can I increase my font sizes without decreasing my resolution?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52602/how-can-i-increase-my-font-sizes-without-decreasing-my-resolution), *Ask Different*, Jun 1 `12

Comment: I completely understand that my monitor only has those resolutions, but what I'm looking is something like fractional scaling, like Windows or some Linux distros have. But my monitor, not being "retina" doesn't allow me to set scaling as I was expecting when I linked that tutorial on the post.