# Changing Finder's Font Size - Lion

Tags: macos, finder

I open My Documents in finder.  Click CMD-J and change the font size to 10.  I choose set as default.  The font size looks right on My Documents.

Then I navigate to Applications, and the font size is 12.

Is there a way I can change my font size on all folders?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have to delete the `.DS_Store` files in each folder.

How to do that? Via [Onyx](http://onyx.softonic.de/mac). You can also unhide all invisible files (`.DS_Store` files are invisible) and delete them one by one.

After that, you can "set default" in the root folder and it should be in all the folders below

> / -> /Applications 
>         / -> /Documents etc.

Comment: Or, more conveniently from a terminal. Go to the parent of where you'd like all the .DS_Store files removed and use `find . -iname ".DS_Store" | xargs rm`

Comment: @CraftyThumber If `rm` was aliased to `rm -r`, there was a path like `~/Some Documents and Stuff/.DS_Store`, and PWD was `~/`, that would delete `~/Documents/`. `find . -name .DS_Store -delete` is much better.

Comment: @LauriRanta, I don't think it would. It would expand to `rm -r /path/to/first/.DS_Store; rm -r /path/to/next/.DS_Store; ...`. It would only be a problem if someone had a directory called .DS_Store (unlikely).

Comment: @CraftyThumber Try running `find . -iname ".DS_Store" | xargs printf '%s\n'`.

Comment: OK, make it `find . -name ".DS_Store" | xargs -0 rm`... You make a good point for a corner case where someone aliases `rm` (which I would never recommend) and they use spaces in their directory names (which I guess isn't that uncommon); +1 to you :)

Comment: Thank you guys!  I ended up using: find . -name ".DS_Store" | xargs -0 rm